# Apache htaccess - change subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My file structure looks like this:

- /
- - index.php
- - htaccess
- - cabinet
- - - public
- - - - file.txt
- - - - index.php

I want to have a redirect from cabinet/file.txt to cabinet/public/file.txt,
and if cabinet/public/$filename does not exists then  to redirect to cabinet/public/index.php instead.

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rewrite rule in Apache. [Here](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) is a good place to start if you are not familiar. What you want looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^cabinet/file.txt    cabinet/public/file.txt

ErrorDocument 404 cabinet/public/index.php
```

Keep in mind that the ErrorDocument will be used for all 404 or files not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this .htaccess in `/cabinet/` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cabinet/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cabinet/public/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/index.php [L,NC]
```